# gratitude to the stack exchange

Tags: support

What can I do to give back  to the forum? The forum gave a lot of sound advice, answered my question, enriched my knowledge, and supported me in my queries. What can I do to give back to the forum?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit low quality posts to improve them.

Once you've gained [enough reputation](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) you'll be able to review posts from other users, to help out with the moderation of the site.

Comment: I still need to learn a lot, you even edited what I wrote!

Comment: I believe most of us still learn from this site

Comment: That is the beauty of sharing knowledge. At the end everyone gains.

Answer (score 6):

Provide good answers to other questions!

Comment: That's for sure. As much capacity I have.

Answer (score 5):

I think one of the best things to do is be welcoming and understanding to users who are even newer than yourself; to help them by explaining how best to use the site, how to stay on-topic, and so on.

An even simpler thing is just to make sure you vote up questions and answers that you've found helpful!

Comment: That's without saying.